# SMS send as a background Service using SmsManager

Tags: android, android-service, android-2.2-froyo

I am trying to create an application in Android 2.2 which sends SMS to 6 different contacts the same msg automatically in background as a `Service` using `android.telephony.SmsManager` which supports both CDMA and GSM.

I saw many threads which has a code snippet but they are using which are deprecated i.e. `import android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager;` so i just replaced it with `import android.telephony.SmsManager` and wrote the following code & it works

```
  SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
  sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentPI, deliveredPI);
```

now ,

> 1) can anyone tell me the `roadmap to create a service` which sends up
>   to 6 SMS in background ?
>
> 2) moreover is it good to create another thread inside a service to
>   send SMS to make it run in a separate thread for fast result ?

i am pretty much new to Android Services section so i am confused **what i need to use Remote Service or Local Service**  , please do ask if you have any question regarding my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You only need to follow the LocalService example depicted [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample)

2) You can use any for of android concurrency as depicted [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html) if you choose to.

Comment: so  to perform concurrency task i need take a reference from RemoteService , a sample supplied in android API demo ?

Comment: No you do not need remote task. Just create and start a thread and execute your code in the run method

Comment: No you just need the LocalService sample not more :)

Comment: To keep the service live you can just return the sticky flag

Comment: @MahdeTo okay , so even i am out of the activity class then also i will be able access it ?

Comment: @Hunt yes, if you use the LocalBinding as provided by the service you can access it from within your application.

Comment: @MahdeTo is it possible that i run a handler when the service starts and then when the handler done with the extra work it acknowledges back to the activity

Comment: Do i need a Messenger to get an acknowledgement from the service

Comment: @HUnt I think all concurrency models are applicable from the service. you can read the 2nd link I sent for a more comprehensive listing.

Answer (score 1):

1) I do not see any reason not to follow the normal way for creating a service. I mean you can just follow the documentation about Service

2) Yes it is good to start a thread to perform actions in the background in a service

Comment: with a normal service implementation can i run that service even if the application is closed right ?