# Background process sending SMS

Tags: android

Folks,

I am working on a project where the requirement is the app launch will not display any screen but will launch a background process that will send out SMS. I have just started on android so I need some pointer on

a) How to launch an app without screen but only with a background process?

b) From that background process how to spawn a thread (I am assuming we need to spawn a thread here) that will send out SMS automatically?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: a/ that's a service. b/ not necessarly

Answer (score 0):

use this code in `onCreate()` of your Activity and write logic of sms in `Service`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Intent intent=new Intent(this,YourService.class);
    startService(intent);
    finish();
}
```

[Send SMS in Background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664002/sms-send-as-a-background-service-using-smsmanager)

Answer (score 0):

You can call finish() immediately right after spawning a background process. You can use IntentService as it automatically spawns its own worker thread to handle every intent. For example:

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        smsManager.sendTextMessage("phoneNumber", null, "your message here", null, null);
    }
}
```

so in the onCreate() of your Activity, you can just simply do something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
startService(intent);
```

Don't forget to add the android.permission.SEND_SMS permission in your manifest.

Comment: I am getting the following exception - W/ActivityManager(275): Unable to start service Intent  U=0: not found

Comment: @user2740002 have you declared the service in your Manifest?

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule message sending from the IntentService through [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) class.